# RSS Autodiscovery gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rss, rubygems, autodiscovery

Does anybody know some RSS Autodiscovery gem in Ruby? I could not find an appropriate gem.

The things that I want gem to do are

1. Do RSS autodiscovery
2. Be applicable into Ruby on Rails 3.2

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I investigated [rfeedfinder](https://github.com/alx/rfeedfinder) is the best for RSS Autodiscovery in Ruby.

Comment: What did you investigate?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two of them:

1. [TruffleHog](https://github.com/pauldix/truffle-hog)
2. [Feedbag](https://github.com/damog/feedbag)

Comment: Thanks @halfelf! I will study them if they are easy to use and work well for RSS Autodiscovery.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that TruffleHog does not have RSS autodiscovery.